# iPhone SDK multitasking with CoreLocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am developing an `iPhone` app which uses `CoreLocation`.
I'm having trouble finding out if the `CoreLocation` location continues to get updated when the app enters the background. I would like to have it stop updating, but I am not sure if I need to explicitly tell it to stop or not.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set whether your application will run in background mode. As documentation says [Background Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Also you notice an icon in status bar will disappear when core location stops updating location data when your app. go to background mode

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the following url .. hope it is useful to you

**http://numiko.com/labs/?p=238**

Answer (score 0):

As with most things, programming related; if you want an action to occur, you almost always need to tell it to do that thing, or an ancillary thing which side effects that.

If you want it to stop updating, tell it to do so. (And yes, there are two different modes that will collect location info in the background. One is only on the iPhone 4 though.)